# trouble connecting to mysql 5.7 on AWS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mysql-5.7

I launched an EC2 instance on AWS and am using Ubuntu. I am able to connect to MySQL on the instance itself. 
(i.e. mysql -h localhost -u root -p)

but when I try and connect from my remote computer 
(i.e. mysql -h ipaddress -u remoteUN -p)

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ipaddress' (61)
```

I have changed my security settings to allow all IP addresses to connect to port 3306, as well as port 22, and on the instance I created a user that can access MySQL from a remote server

```
> CREATE USER 'tempuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'tempuser'@'%'
> WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I tried to start/stop the mysql server using

```
 > service mysqld restart
```

and get the following

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'mysqld.service'.
```

Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:

I'm not sure what the default password is, and when I enter my MySQL password I get

```
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to restart mysqld.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.

> systemctl status mysqld.service
  mysqld.service
  Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
  Active: inactive (dead)
```

Anyone know what default password is or how to restart the server so that I can connect remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is disabled by default is remote `root` access. If you want to enable that, run this SQL command locally:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Now as of not being able to connect remotely you will have to **comment out** `bind ip`line in `my.cnf` file which usually lives on `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Unix/OSX systems. In some cases the location for the file is `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`).

Find the Line :

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1` 
and comment it out by adding `#` in front of it save and restart mysql , you should be able to connect to it remotely.

Hope this helps !